How to set the value of os.environ in python using the command line?
OS:Win10
reg add HKCU\Environment /F /V http_proxy /d "http://127.0.0.1:8080"
reg add HKCU\Environment /F /V https_proxy /d "http://127.0.0.1:8080"

I'm pretty sure this is the only place where the variable is set. http_proxy is no longer in the variables shown by set
After deleting it in this way. It is still output the variable values.
import os

print(os.environ['http_proxy'])
print(os.environ['https_proxy'])

python.exe F:\Fshare\del1\vmware\test\del\f5\a.py 
http://127.0.0.1:8080
http://127.0.0.1:8080

How can I get the variables to update instantly and clear the cache.

Those commands don't delete anything. And as far as I know this won't effect the env variables anyway.

Are these variables set in your powershell $PROFILE or shell configuration? Also, have you restarted your shell before rerunning? Apologies if you have already considered these.

This isn't really a Python question, as the answer depends more on how your run your program (whether written in Python or not). I suggest replacing python with windows and/or powershell.

Please take a look on What is the reason for "X is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"? This long answer explains on the most important environment variable PATH how the environment variables management work on Windows. You must at least sign out / log out and sign in / log in with your user account to get the user environment variable changes applied to processes started with your account. Best is a restart of Windows to get the environment variables of all running processes updated.

The deletion of environment variables can be done in the current command prompt window by running set http_proxy= and set https_proxy=. Then run Python for interpreting the Python script. For a persistent deletion of the two user environment variables can be clicked on Windows Start button, typed on keyboard environment, clicked on suggested item Edit environment variables for your account, and selected and deleted the two environment variables on the upper pane of the Environment Variables configuration window.

Doing the same with %SystemRoot%\System32\reg.exe requires the execution of reg DELETE HKCU\Environment /v http_proxy /f and reg DELETE HKCU\Environment /v https_proxy /f. Please run in the command prompt window first reg /? and next reg delete /? and read the output usage helps. Do not guess the syntax to use of the Windows command REG. That is really dangerous for the stability of your Windows PC.

The deletion of the persistent stored user environment variables changes nothing in the environment variables list in the memory of any already running process like cmd.exe running as Command Prompt with the exception of explorer.exe running as Windows shell and of applications written for handling the WM_SETTINGCHANGE message like Total Commander on doing the modification with the GUI window Environment Variables. The deletion of persistent stored environment variables with REG does not cause a send of the WM_SETTINGCHANGE message. Restart of Windows is recommended.

Run this from your cmd (instead of tinkering with registry):
setx http_proxy "http://127.0.0.1:8080"
setx https_proxy "http://127.0.0.1:8080"

to quote cmd description setx
Creates or modifies environment variables in the user or system
environment. Can set variables based on arguments, regkeys or
file input.


Best would be clicking on the Windows Start button, typing on keyboard environment (works with all OS languages), clicking on suggested item Edit environment variables for your account, and add/edit user environment variables using the GUI. However, neither the add/edit of user environment variables with the GUI nor with the executable setx which can be also used in this case changes anything on the environment variables of an already running process like cmd.exe. The user most close the opened command prompt and open a new one from Windows shell (desktop, start menu).

The simple solution for the current command prompt window is the execution of set "http_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:8080" and set "https_proxy=http://127.0.0.1:8080" and then start Python for interpreting a Python script. But in real the original poster wants to delete the environment variables which can be done in the current command prompt window with set http_proxy= and set https_proxy= before  starting Python for interpreting a Python script.
